# Database structure adaptation for client

Tags: database, database-design

I'm currently running a First aid database for the workplace. Initially they only wanted people who work in the business to be able to register as first aiders, therefore they used the persons payroll number to differentiate(unique_indentifier). But now they want people not working in the business to be able to register. Any suggestions on how I would achieve this without the outsiders being given a payroll number?

Comment: I think you should add a lot more information, as well as maybe showing the current schema (only the interessting part) and so on. Probably you will find a solution yourself while trying to collect and show all the data.

Comment: Alter the database to use a blind primary key, and make the payroll number a nullable column.  This is why an auto-incrmenting integer or long, or some other non-business unique identifier should **always** be used as a primary (clustering) key.

Comment: @Gilbert Auto-incrementing integers are not very useful as a [clustered index](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/glossar/clustered-index). It is also not true they are "always" the best choice for a primary key (although they often are).